# Adding Mailchimp (MC4WP) checkbox to Woocommerce My Account registration form

Tags: woocommerce, mailchimp

I want to add a checkbox for people to subscribe to my Mailchimp when registering an account on my Woocommerce store. MC4WP provide the following code:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="mc4wp-subscribe" value="1" />
    Sign-up to our newsletter.
</label>
```

How can I add this in to that form? Ideally with a snippet I can place in Codesnippets.

Thank you!

Comment: Normally when creating a form, MC4WP automatically provide a short code that you can then use?

Comment: Hi there, yes it has provided the shortcode that I have used on several parts of the site. This displays a form for entering name and email.  What I want to do is use the Woo new user registration on 'My Account' page, and add a checkbox to use those details to add to Mailchimp list.

Answer (score -1):

you can easily add in the custom HTML field.

[image]